# How do I include other directives in the template of my customer directive in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wrote a simple custom directive. The *template* in this directive includes other directives (e.g. `ui-sortable`). Because it doesn't *always* use ui-sortable, I add it in the link phase. Yet it doesn't seem to apply:

```
        link: function ($scope,$element,attrs) {
attrs.$observe('admin', function(value) {
  if ($scope.admin) {
        $element.find("span").html("true");
      $element.find("ul").attr("ui:sortable","sortableOptions");
  }
});
    }
```

Full fiddle example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/VjfEf/4/

There are two lists. The first uses `ui-sortable` directly and drag/drop/sort works, the second uses my custom `members` directive. The directive does work, it renders, but the addition of `ui-sortable` in the exact same way as the first has no impact and drag/drop/sort does not.

I am assuming I am not understanding something about the processing phases of custom directives, and either need to add something to my custom directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compile the newly added HTML.

```
$compile($element.contents())($scope);
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VjfEf/6/)</kbd>

Comment: Can you expand on that, please? Where/when do I compile it? Feel free to modify the fiddle and update.

Comment: Brilliant @CodeHater, it works quite nicely. Am I doing this backwards, is there a better way to do this? My understanding is that since I am manipulating the DOM of the template, and it will be different for each instance, that has to happen in the link phase?

Comment: Still having some issues with cross-list-DnD. I will update the fiddle and post here...

Comment: @deitch Or you can post a different question.

Comment: K, I will do that. Referencing this one.

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001170/in-angular-directive-that-compiles-template-with-ui-sortable-run-twice-with-co